# How to calculate cubic feet in C and read it to the user like I did with inches

Tags: c, units-of-measurement

I am having an issue on how I would construct my length height and width to calculate in Cubic feet. I have already calculated it in Cubic inches, I was just confused on how to set it up without using any conditionals and just use data types and mixed data types allowed. I am just having an issue structuring the code to show up and calculate right, but I am kind of lost on how to do that in code. I tried, so here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    //Initialized variables of Length, height, and width of a box.
    double length_of_box, height_of_box, width_of_box;
    double cubicInches_of_box, cubicFeet_of_box;


    //prompt and read the size of box to the user for them to enter in length, height, and width.
    printf("What is the size of your box in length, height, and width in inches?\n");
    scanf("%lf", &length_of_box);
    scanf("%lf", &height_of_box);
    scanf("%lf", &width_of_box);
    printf("Your box\'s Dimension\'s\n length: %.1lf\n Height: %.2lf\n Width: %.3lf\n ", length_of_box, height_of_box, width_of_box);
    //Calculates volume of box in cubic inches.
    cubicInches_of_box = length_of_box*height_of_box*width_of_box;

    printf("The volume of your box: %.2lf cubic inches.\n", cubicInches_of_box);

    //Calculates volume of box in cubic feet.
    cubicFeet_of_box = cubicInches_of_box/2;

    printf("The volume of your box: %.2lf cubic feet.\n",cubicFeet_of_box);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation

```
cubicFeet_of_box = cubicInches_of_box/2;
```

should be

```
cubicFeet_of_box = cubicInches_of_box/1728;  // 12*12*12
```

What other problems are you having?

Comment: I see that, but I need it to fit the dimensions of specific height length and width. Forgot to add that on there.  Length:  15.8
Width:  23.34
Height: 75.345
Is the exact numbers I have to enter to calculate the cubic feet of.

Comment: So you enter "15.8 23.34 75.345" at the prompt, and your program tells you the box is 27785.13 cubic inches and 16.08 cubic feet.  What's the problem?

Comment: I am not dividing it by the right height width and length in inches. The number you gave me 1728 is for 12 by 12 by 12 not 15.8 by 23.34 by 75.345.

Comment: There are 12 inches in a foot, that's why you divide the number of inches in each dimension by 12.  15.8 inches is 1.32 feet, for example.

Comment: Okay, this helps. Sorry, its been a while since a math class and I am a novice in C. Voted up, cheers!

Comment: @FKEinternet Consider [Is it ok to ask to upvote/accept my own answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271810/2410359)

Answer (score 2):

Your conversion factor is wrong.  The number of cubic feet is not half the number of cubic inches.  The proper conversion:

1 cubic foot = 1 ft * 1 ft * 1 ft = 12 in * 12 in * 12 in = 1728 cubic inches

So you need to divide cubic inches by 1728 to get cubic feet.